# Showing page Loader when rel="external"

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-loader

I am navigating to an external html page in jQuery Mobile application. the page takes a while loading i want to show loader in mean time but  its not working.. here is what i have tried..

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        //  $.mobile.loading('show');
        $.mobile.loading( "show", {
                    text: 'Please Wait!',
                    textVisible: 'true',
                    theme: "b",
                    textonly: 'true',
                    html: ''
            });

        });

        $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        });
```

I know rel="external" disables ajax, Is there there any way i can show this loader opening external links..?

Comment: It's not possible because page isn't loaded via Ajax and DOM is replaced with new page's DOM.

Comment: @Omar : is there any traditional way to do it via pure JS ..? I just need to show a Please Wait tag.. thats it...

Comment: The only way to show loader before page is hidden is to delay showing next page.

Comment: @Omar : can you please show me a demo or refer me to a link with some info about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move to an *external* page with Ajax disabled, the *loader* doesn't show because DOM is wiped and replaced with contents of that *external* page.

The only possible way to show *loader* before navigating is to *delay* moving to that page by `setTimeout()`.

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.*****.com" rel="external" class="ui-btn external">External Page</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
    $(".external").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $.mobile.loading("show", {
            text: "redirecting...",
            textVisible: true
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.href = url;
        }, 2000); // 2secs delay
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VvLz4/show)** - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VvLz4/)**